# jscrollpane content is shown 3 times

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

using jscrollpane my content is duplicated 3 times.
to see what i mean go to:
http://www.facesoflyme.com/view_pets/profile/pet_webpage.php?pet_id=1676
and view the scrolling content under "Casey's Lyme Disease Journey"

here is the same page without using jscrollpanel. Notice the content is only shown one time.
use the url below to view the page that works
pet_webpage_11302010.php?pet_id=1676

If anyone can help figure out how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're adding this content there 3 times:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode"> 
$(function()
{
// Initialise the scrollpanes
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
// Add some content to #pane2
var pane2api = $('#pane2').data('jsp');
var originalContent = pane2api.getContentPane().html();
pane2api.getContentPane().html(originalContent + originalContent + originalContent);
// Reinitialise the #pane2 scrollpane
pane2api.reinitialise();
});
</script>
```

This line:

```
pane2api.getContentPane().html(originalContent + originalContent + originalContent);
```

The content is already there as a static HTML, the only thing you need to do is use this:
`$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();`
that will do for most of the implementations

Cheers

G.